# C# Sending Windows Mail using .docx text content

Tags: c#

I need to get .docx formatted text and then prepare sending it in windows Mail app (not sending with stmp, just open windows Mail and paste the word text into the body).

I already tried to copy paste it with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word but the text is not formatted.
This is my code to send mail/get Word content:

Thank you for your help !

```
       Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(fileName);

            string allWords = doc.Content.Text;
            doc.Close();
            app.Quit();

            string mailto = string.Format("mailto:{0}?Subject={1}&Body={2}", destinataire.Text, objet.Text, allWords);
            mailto = Uri.EscapeUriString(mailto);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mailto);
```